# How to receive a previous line of text from an Stack in Java

Tags: java, stack

I am currently struggling with a code. The problem mainly occurs with the array and trying to reach back.

This file only requires a main method that does the following until the user enters "quit":

• Prompts the user for a URL to visit, to go back (only when possible), or to quit

• Visits and displays an entered URL

• Goes back to and displays the previously visited URL (if possible)

• If the user enters "back" when there isn't a page to go back to, an appropriate message should be displayed.

Here's an example of an output:

Enter a URL or "quit": back

No URL to go back to

Enter a URL or "quit": http://www.wwe.com

Current URL: http://www.wwe.com

Enter a URL or "quit": back

No URL to go back to

Current URL: http://www.wwe.com

Enter a URL or "quit": http://www.amazon.com

Current URL: http://www.amazon.com

Enter a URL, "back", or "quit": http://www.google.com

Current URL: http://www.google.com

Enter a URL, "back", or "quit": back

Current URL: http://www.amazon.com

Enter a URL, "back", or "quit": back

Current URL: http://www.wwe.com

Enter a URL or "quit": quit

Here's my current code:

```
public class BrowsingHistory
{
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {

    Scanner url = new Scanner(System.in);
    String web = "";
    String currentURL = "";
    Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<>();
    System.out.print("Enter a URL or \"quit\": ");
    web = url.nextLine();
    while (!web.contains("quit"))
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter a URL, \"back\", or \"quit\": ");
        web = url.nextLine();
        if(web.equals("back") && myStack.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("No URL to go back to");

        }
            else if(!web.equals("back"))
            {
                myStack.push(web);
                System.out.println("Current URL: " + myStack.peek());
            }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("No URL to go back to");
                    System.out.println("Current URL: " + myStack.pop());
        }
        }
}
}
```

Here are the tests it needs to pass, just so it's clarified:

```
 @Test
 void testMain()
 {
     setInput("back\nhttp://www.uwec.edu\nback\nhttp://www.amazon.com\nhttp://.    w.google.com\nback\nback\nquit\n");

BrowsingHistory.main(null);

 String mainOutput = outContent.toString();

  Scanner driverOut = new Scanner(mainOutput);

     String outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);

    assertEquals("Enter a URL or \"quit\":", outputLine.substring(0, outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (initial prompt problem)");
```

Error happens in this line below:

```
    assertEquals("No URL to go back to", outputLine.substring(outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (can't go back issue)");
```

the rest of this passes:

```
    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Enter a URL or \"quit\":", outputLine.substring(0, outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (prompt problem)");
    assertEquals("Current URL: http://www.uwec.edu", outputLine.substring(outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (current url problem)");

    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Enter a URL or \"quit\":", outputLine.substring(0, outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (prompt problem)");
    assertEquals("No URL to go back to", outputLine.substring(outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (can't go back issue)");

    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Current URL: http://www.uwec.edu", outputLine.trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (current url problem)");

    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Enter a URL or \"quit\":", outputLine.substring(0, outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (prompt problem)");
    assertEquals("Current URL: http://www.amazon.com", outputLine.substring(outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (current url problem)");

    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Enter a URL, \"back\", or \"quit\":", outputLine.substring(0, outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (prompt problem)");
    assertEquals("Current URL: http://www.google.com", outputLine.substring(outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (current url problem)");

    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Enter a URL, \"back\", or \"quit\":", outputLine.substring(0, outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (prompt problem)");
    assertEquals("Current URL: http://www.amazon.com", outputLine.substring(outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (current url problem)");

    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Enter a URL, \"back\", or \"quit\":", outputLine.substring(0, outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (prompt problem)");
    assertEquals("Current URL: http://www.uwec.edu", outputLine.substring(outputLine.indexOf(":")+1).trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (current url problem)");

    outputLine = getNextOutputLine(driverOut);
    assertEquals("Enter a URL or \"quit\":", outputLine.trim(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (prompt problem)");

    assertFalse(driverOut.hasNext(), "BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (quit problem)");

    driverOut.close();
}
```

Comment: better implement linked list, that is more convenience to navigate, in your case

Comment: @subash what exactly do you mean by that? Sorry, I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: You are keeping track of the current index with `count`, yes? You can go back if the current index is `> 0`, otherwise you'd print your message. You could also use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html) which provides an API to scroll the `List`, including methods to add and remove elements.

Comment: @Slaw understood, where would I place it in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stack class instead of an ArrayList would make your life much easier.

Use push() to add new urls to stack.

Use empty() to check if you can go back.

Use pop() to go back.

**EDIT - supporting forward**

If you want to support a 'forward' comand as well, you can use a second stack and push the urls you popped from the history stack on that forward-stack. When the 'forward' command is entered, check, if the forward-stack is empty, and if not, pop the url from there and push it back onto the history-stack.

**EDIT 2 - example code**

Here is some rudimentry code to explain the 2 stacks solution:

```
Stack<String> historyStack = new Stack<>();
Stack<String> forwardStack = new Stack<>();
String currentUrl = null;

boolean running = true;
while(running) {
    String input = getUserInput();
    switch(input) {
        case "quit":
            running = false;
            break;
        case "back":               
            if (!historyStack.empty()) {
                if (currentUrl != null) {
                    forwardUrl.push(currentUrl);
                }
                currentUrl = historyStack.pop();
                System.out.println(currentUrl);
            } else {
                System.out.println("nothing to go back to");
            }
            break;
        case "forward":
            if (!forwardStack.empty()) {
                if (currentUrl != null) {
                    historyStack.push(currentUrl);
                }
                currentUrl = forwardStack.pop();
                System.out.println(url);
            } else {
                System.out.println("nothing to go forward to");
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (currentUrl != null) {
                historyStack.push(currentUrl);
            }
            currentUrl = input;
            System.out.println(url);
            // entering a new url makes forward stack invalid
            forwardStack.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm working on. I finished my Stack class with all of those methods you just put up. Please show me a code to this, it would help a lot, because I wasn't certain if I could do those.

Comment: what about the forward case?, if we use stack, item will gone, so cant forward

Comment: There is no forward case mentioned in the question

Comment: However, you can use a second stack for that and push the urls you popped from the history stack onto that second stack.

Comment: I have a class with Stack methods that I created. I have a question in regards to that, but I already have it answered. You can look at the code in there, it links with this one.

Comment: I added some example code to my answer (fixed some errors, my first code had)

Comment: @AdanVivero So this happens at the beginning of the test, with the first input? Try to debug the test run, and post what the actual value is, compared to the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your logic to as follows :

```
ArrayList<String> webs = new ArrayList<String>();
String web = "";
Scanner url = new Scanner(System.in);

int count = 0;
while (!web.contains("quit")) {
    System.out.println("Enter a URL or \"quit\":");
    web = url.next();
    if (!web.equals("back")) {
        webs.add(web);
        count = webs.size();
    } else if (web.equals("back") && !webs.isEmpty()) {
        if (count > 0) {
            count--;
            System.out.println(webs.get(count));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No url to go back to");
        }
    }
}
```

Note the following points :

1. We add only *Strings* that are not equal to *back*
2. In your previous implementation the first *url* entered was not getting inserted into your list.
3. After an element is added to the *list*, count is reset to the size of the list.

---

As others have pointed out, the same can be achieved much more easily by using a *Stack*

```
Scanner url = new Scanner(System.in);
String web = "";
Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<>();
while (!web.contains("quit")) {
    System.out.println("Enter a URL or \"quit\":");
    web = url.next();
    if (!web.equals("back") && !web.equals("quit")) {
        myStack.push(web);
    } else {
        if (!myStack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(myStack.pop());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No url to go back to");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about running it without using "tests" first?

Comment: It works great when I run it on main, however it doesn't pass my tests. Might just be minor errors like spelling and stuff that I have to look over.

Comment: Would it help if I put down the tests that need to be passed?

Comment: Also, I've added an implementation using a *Stack*. Maybe your *test cases* will pass using that. Also *debugging* the test cases will help you figure it out.

Comment: Agreed, I do have a stack class to be honest. Should I use those methods as mentioned before?

Comment: alright, I keep receiving the same error on the same line. I will point it out up above which line in the tests I receive the error from.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Where exactly is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect data structure. `List` is OK, but using `Stack` is more correct here: you add to the end and retrieve from the end, this id **LIFO**.

```
private static final String QUIT = "quit";
private static final String BACK = "back";

try (Scanner url = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    Deque<String> stack = new LinkedList<>();

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a URL, \"" + BACK + "\" or \"" + QUIT + "\": ");
        String str = url.next();

        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(QUIT))
            break;
        else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(BACK)) {
            if (!stack.isEmpty())
                stack.pop();
            System.out.println(stack.isEmpty() ? "No URL to go back to" : stack.element());
        } else
            stack.push(str);
    }
}
```

---

**Demo**

```
Enter a URL, "back" or "QUIT": http://www.wwe.com
Enter a URL, "back" or "QUIT": http://www.amazon.com
Enter a URL, "back" or "QUIT": http://www.google.com
Enter a URL, "back" or "QUIT": back
http://www.amazon.com
Enter a URL, "back" or "QUIT": back
http://www.wwe.com
Enter a URL, "back" or "QUIT": back
No URL to go back to
Enter a URL, "back" or "QUIT": quit
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error when I run my tests. BrowsingHistory doesn't run as expected (current url problem) ==> 
Expected :Current URL: http://www.uwec.edu
Actual   :Enter a URL or "quit": No URL to go back to